# I can't get the results of the interrogation.(postgresql and php)

Tags: php, postgresql

I want to search by output but I am doing wrong where it somehow doesn't work. I am using PostgreSQL.

```
SELECT 
      CDR.xml_cdr_uuid,
        CDR.direction,
        CDR.caller_id_number,
        CDR.destination_number,
        CDR.start_stamp,
        CDR.end_stamp,
        CDR.duration,
        CDR.record_path,
        CDR.record_name,
CASE  
           WHEN (bridge_uuid is not null) and (answer_stamp is not null) and billsec >0  THEN 'answer'
             WHEN (missed_call = true and bridge_uuid is null) AND (json->'variables'->>'sip_invite_failure_status' IN('487','486','480') ) THEN 'not_call'
             WHEN (answer_stamp is not NULL) and (bridge_uuid is NULL) AND (sip_hangup_disposition !='send_refuse') THEN 'voicemail'
             ELSE 'ROTA_error' END
        as status
FROM v_xml_cdr as CDR
GROUP BY  xml_cdr_uuid
HAVING    ('status' = 'not_call')
```

[image]

Comment: Hello Zelemi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Your query apparently returns no rows. We can't tell why without seeing sample data and desired results (both as tabular text).

Comment: Hello there,
Having 'status' = 'not_call' does not work when I query.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think `HAVING    ('status' = 'not_call')` is wrong

Comment: can you try `HAVING (status = 'not_call')`

Comment: I'm getting this error.
 > ERROR:  column "status" does not exist
LINE 22:  HAVING (status='not_call')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
      CDR.xml_cdr_uuid,
        CDR.direction,
        CDR.caller_id_number,
        CDR.destination_number,
        CDR.start_stamp,
        CDR.end_stamp,
        CDR.duration,
        CDR.record_path,
        CDR.record_name,
CASE  
           WHEN (bridge_uuid is not null) and (answer_stamp is not null) and billsec >0  THEN 'answer'
             WHEN (missed_call = true and bridge_uuid is null) AND (json->'variables'->>'sip_invite_failure_status' IN('487','486','480') ) THEN 'not_call'
             WHEN (answer_stamp is not NULL) and (bridge_uuid is NULL) AND (sip_hangup_disposition !='send_refuse') THEN 'voicemail'
             ELSE 'ROTA_error' END
        as status
FROM v_xml_cdr as CDR
GROUP BY  xml_cdr_uuid
HAVING    (CASE  
           WHEN (bridge_uuid is not null) and (answer_stamp is not null) and billsec >0  THEN 'answer'
             WHEN (missed_call = true and bridge_uuid is null) AND (json->'variables'->>'sip_invite_failure_status' IN('487','486','480') ) THEN 'not_call'
             WHEN (answer_stamp is not NULL) and (bridge_uuid is NULL) AND (sip_hangup_disposition !='send_refuse') THEN 'voicemail'
             ELSE 'ROTA_error' END = 'not_call')
```

You trying to compare two strings, the string `'status'` and string `'not call'` in your `HAVING` clause. So, everytime this comparison will be `false`

Comment: Thanks yes, this worked and gave results.
Thank you so much